# htaccess RewriteRule URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to Rewrite a bunch of URLs looking like this:

http://example.com/test/gallery/?view=gallery&gallery=214

to

http://example.com/gallery/?view=gallery&gallery=214

I think the url after gallery/ isnt important? Just want to get rid of the "test" inbetween there.

I already tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ test?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

example code htaccess rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```